# Cannot close window without process associated

Tags: windows, visual-studio, process, handle, terminate

I'm writing and then debugging a console application in VC++ 2008, it then happens that closing Visual Studio IDE, the console window remain opened, and there is no way to close it!
Also if I try a machine reboot the machine doesn't restart. The only way is turning off the power.
In the process list there are no signs of the console window.
If I try to investigate the console window with tools like Spy++ I found the window but in the "process" tab there is a process ID that doesn't exists, in the "General" tab the "window proc" field says "Unavailable".
How is it possible? 
How can I kill those type of windows as there is no processe to kill?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most annoying bug ever; get the [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982551).

Comment: wow! it's exactly my situation and the hotfix solved it. Thank you very much